# Iterate all the machines in a for loop in parallel and check whether they are up or down?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, executorservice

I have list of machines in an `ArrayList`. I am checking whether all those machines are up or not so I am making a http call on them and if they respond so they are up but if they don't respond then they are down. I considered them dead if they don't respond for 10 retries meaning each machine I retry 10 times if they don't respond.

Now I need to iterate that `hostnames` list in parallel in a for loop so I came up with below code. Is there any multithreading issues or anything can be improved here? Am I using executor service correctly here?

```
  private static final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<String> hostnames = new ArrayList<>();
    //.. populating hostnames

    List<Future<Void>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<Void>>();
    for (final String machine : hostnames) {
      Callable<Void> callable = new Callable<Void>() {
        public Void call() throws Exception {
          String url = "http://" + machine + ":8080/ruok";
          if (!checkServer(url)) {
            System.out.println("server down: " + machine);
          }
          return null;
        }
      };
      futures.add(executorService.submit(callable));
    }
    executorService.shutdown();
    for (Future<Void> future : futures) {
      future.get();
    }
    System.out.println("All done!");
  }

  private static boolean checkServer(final String url) {
    boolean isUp = false;
    int retry = 10;
    for (int i = 1; i <= retry; i++) {
      try {
        RestClient.getInstance().getClient().getForObject(url, String.class);
        isUp = true;
        break;
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        // log exception
      }
    }
    return isUp;
  }
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code?

Comment: works fine but since it is multithreading so I am not sure whether I am missing any corner cases here which can lead to issues for me after some time

Comment: Maybe this question belongs in the Code Review Stack Exchange?

Comment: maybe but I am not sure since there might be a bug in this code because of multithreading which I am not sure

Comment: @Erik https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266749/migration-of-code-questions-from-stack-overflow-to-code-review/269283#269283

Comment: @YvetteColomb: That link confused me a bit but this one makes it clear https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253975/be-careful-when-recommending-code-review-to-askers

Comment: @Erik ah thanks, will add that to the community wiki we're compiling. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368693/why-was-my-custom-flag-declined-when-should-i-use-a-custom-flag